# PyQt QTextEdit forgetting settings

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtextedit

I've got a PyQt GUI with a `QTextEdit` in it. I have set a few of the widget settings to play with things like the font size. What I'm seeing is that when I initially type in the field, the settings are applied, but if I delete all text and start typing again, the settings have reset to the default ones. Below is a MWE where I can see this behavior. Just in case it matters, I'm using Python 3.5.1 with PyQt4 4.8.7.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])   # The main application
        self.win = QtGui.QMainWindow()      # The main window
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()       # The central widget in the main window
        self.grid = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()     # The layout manager of the central widget

        self.textArea = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textArea)
        self.textArea.setMinimumSize(600,300)
        self.textArea.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.textArea.setFontPointSize(12)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.win.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.win.show()
        self.app.exec_()

App()
```

Comment: Typically `App` would inherit from `QApplication`, i.e. `class App(QtGui.QApplication):`. That may have something to do with it.

Comment: @101 Changing to do this results in the same behavior. I wouldn't have expected this to have an effect. I'm wondering if this isn't just some bug.

Comment: @zephyr. All I can see is that the font point-size changes, which is exactly as expected.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, I do set it to change. But I'm seeing that if I type in the window, then delete everything and start typing again, the new text suddenly reverts to the initial font size.

Comment: @zephyr. And that behaviour is exactly as per the docs for `setFontPointSize`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I don't see anything that indicates the settings will revert back to default values if the text edit field becomes empty again. And if that is the case, how do I ensure these settings don't revert?

Comment: It sets the **current** format. Use `setFont` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new QFont item and then you can use QTextEdit.setFont()

This way it will not reset after all text is deleted.

Comment: Yes this works! What an odd behavior. The documentation was not clear to me that current meant temporary.